# Business Date and Route Sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Route |Sequence|        Planned Time       |     Business Date     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10-1 |   1    |  2015-08-21 20:15:00.000  |      2015-08-21       |
| 10-1 |   2    |  2015-08-22 00:30:00.000  |      2015-08-21       |
| 10-1 |   3    |  2015-08-22 08:45:00.000  |      2015-08-21       |
| 22-1 |   1    |  2015-08-20 17:30:00.000  |      2015-08-20       |
| 22-1 |   2    |  2015-08-21 01:10:00.000  |      2015-08-20       |
| 22-1 |   3    |  2015-08-21 06:30:00.000  |      2015-08-20       |
+------+--------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
```

The above diagram is the ultimate goal... but I need help.

Shipment and deliveries are done everyday of the week, however, only recorded as Business dates, Mon-Fri. Every delivery on sat and Sun is to be recorded as Friday's Business Date. The noon-to-noon logic is for the complexity of route departure times and their uniquely sequence dependence on one another. Route 1A leaves at 8pm on Mon and has 15 sequential stops along the way, one of those stops is the start of Route 1B, and this continues. The nice thing is everyone of these routes, 1st sequential starting time is before noon.

So, in our business structure our routes run overnight. I'm trying to create a standard for Business Date by taking the earliest sequence of that route's "Planned Time" and applying that as the business date if it started the previous day.

My current script looks like this:

```
Case When datepart(dw, Planned Time ) = 1 --and DATEPART(hour,Planned Time )<=12
  then convert(date,dateadd(day,0,(dateadd(dd, - 2, Planned Time )  )))
When datepart(dw, Planned Time ) = 2 and DATEPART(hour,Planned Time )<=12
then CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(DAY,0,Planned Time ))  
When datepart(dw, Planned Time ) = 3 and DATEPART(hour,Planned Time )<=12
then CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(DAY,0,Planned Time )) 
When datepart(dw, Planned Time ) = 4 and DATEPART(hour,Planned Time )<=12
then CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(DAY,0,Planned Time )) 
        When datepart(dw, s.stp_schdtearliest) = 5 
        and DATEPART(hour,s.stp_schdtearliest)<=12
then CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(DAY,0,Planned Time )) 
        When datepart(dw, s.stp_schdtearliest) = 6 
        and DATEPART(hour,Planned Time )<=12
then CONVERT(Date,DATEADD(DAY,0,Planned Time )) 
When datepart(dw, s.stp_schdtearliest) = 7 --and DATEPART(hour,Planned Time )<=12
THEN convert(date,dateadd(day,0,(dateadd(dd, - 1, Planned Time )  )))
ELSE CONVERT(Date,Planned Time ) END BusinessDate
```

*This works for the most part, But the sequences of a route that rolls into the next day will take on the next day's business date too.* -- So it didn't quite work.

Comment: What does your table schema look like?

Answer (score 5):

Given the sample data, here is my first try:

```
SELECT 
  [Route], 
  [Sequence] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY [Route] ORDER BY [Planned Time]),  
  [Planned Time], 
  [Business Date] = MIN(CONVERT(DATE, [Planned Time])) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY [Route])
FROM dbo.table_name
ORDER BY [Route], [Sequence];
```

I am sure there are edge cases you haven't mentioned, though, and I suspect your route numbers can repeat. If the latter is true, you'll need to indicate how to identify whether a row belongs to "that day" or the previous day. If it literally means "anything before noon, including noon, belongs to the previous day" then try:

```
SELECT 
  [Route], 
  [Sequence] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY [Route], CONVERT(DATE, pt) ORDER BY [Planned Time]),  
  [Planned Time], 
  [Business Date] = CONVERT(DATE, pt)
FROM 
( 
  SELECT [Route], [Planned Time], 
    pt = DATEADD(HOUR, -12, [Planned Time])
  FROM dbo.table_name
  -- WHERE ?
) AS x
ORDER BY [Route], [Sequence];
```

These are all bad column names by the way - you should avoid keywords, reserved words, and special characters like spaces.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm doing this in a 2 week rolling basis.  Sorry it didn't work, I think there'll have to be another aggregation to what you've done. What happens now is the business date takes on the date of the 1st sequence of the route, but then applies it for all occurrences of that route.  It will need to adjust to the week, It should have 5 business dates in which it falls in, Mon-Friday.  I think I tried this approach, but forgot about it.

Comment: @TnL If neither answer works for you, then you're going to need to do a better job of supplying enough sample data to reproduce the problem, and also clearly outlining your schema (I know where `[Planned Time]` is, but where the heck does `s.stp_schdtearliest` come from? Why do you care about the noon cutoff only on weekdays? Your problem statement is far from complete and virtually impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: @TnL You need to stop changing the question. [Please read this in its entirety before adding another single detail to the question or any answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). It might not be a bad idea to read [this blog post](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/), either.

Comment: @TnL ***Please*** put that information into the question. Also explain why - if "1st sequential starting time is before noon" - did you assign sequence number 1 to the first row, which has a starting time of 8:15 PM? This seems to conflict with your comment. Does the start of a route happen before noon, after noon, or none of the above? How do I identify that row as the start of the route?

Comment: Clarifying Route 10-1 and this is the actual table from our db, it runs everyday starting Mon-Fri starting with the 1st delivery point at 8:15 PM of 08/21/2015,  then the 2nd delivery is 12:30 AM and the last stop is 8:45 AM.  The whole route's business date would then be 08/21/2015.  The diagram is what I'm trying to achieve.  Sadly with my script the route sequences that  fall into the noon-to-noon logic falls out of Business date sequence.  Maybe I'll need to group it by Route for business date or something...still trying...Thank you Arron for patience and continual help.